# using JMeter proxy recorder behind company proxy with SSL manager

Tags: jmeter

Hi I am facing following issue when try to use JMeter proxy recorder behind company proxy

There are two environments one is not using company proxy(QA env) other is using company proxy(UAT env)

Also both sites are using client side certificate to identify user(saml2).

When recording in the QA environment I only need to use ssl manager and when I start the jmeter proxy jmeter will ask for browser certificate password. After providing that I can successfully record the requests.

But when access the UAT env directly I have to set the browser proxy setting  (webprox.corp.net and port 2212)

So to record the same application I started JMeter using following command

jmeter.bat -H webprox.corp.net  -P 2212

also set the browser proxy settings to localhost and 8080(same as jmeter proxy server settings)

Jmetr recording start fine and requests are captured but it does not evaluate the browser certificate which is loaded in SSL manager. Therefore I am unable to recorded correct scenario as connection says not authorized due to browser certificate unidentification.

Any suggestions on this pls

Comment: Are you able to use a browser through the company proxy without issues? (Without using jmeter at all)

Comment: yes of course. I am accessing to the same UAT env web app via browser without using jmeter. As a solution I can use Blazemeter chrome plugin to record the scenario. But in this case i need to find a solution to do this via JMeter test script recorder. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the solution for above issue

As stated we can start the JMeter  using jmeter.bat -H webprox.corp.net -P 2212 -N localhost (you can use other parameters as required like username and password for the proxy)

Load the valid browser side certificate(not the JMeter root CA) in to the SSL manager(Assume you are not loading certificates from java Keystore)

The main point I have missed was the value in JMter Work Bench > HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder > HTTP Sampler Setting > **Type**

**Had to use Java implementation as Type (or you can change the value and check)**

After completing above configurations I have successfully recorded the script from behind the cooperate proxy.